# smartgwt disable [+] from TreeNode

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I have got simple grid and i am loading data on demand so autofetchdata is set false.

But i need also implemented drop element into this grid , previously when i am load data i know all element and have got info if folder  have got subfolders. if folder have got subfolder i add setIsFrolder to true or false if not so i haven`t got icon [+] if folder havent got any subfolders. 
But when i do that i cannot drop any element into empty folder :/

so i set that all element is folder. But i have got icon [+] when folder is empty. 
I cannot found any flags to disable this ... Its possible to do this ??

Answer (score 2):

Try to call the `setChildren(new TreeNode[0])` on these kind of nodes.